# How to use encrypted password with sftp login?

Tags: bash, shell, sftp, password-encryption

I want to write a shell script where user interaction is not allowed and I want to use sftp login with in the script. Now I have few challenges to execute this approach.

- There is no user interaction so I can only provide the options as a argument while executing the script. Script can be like this.

```
#!/bin/bash

if [[ "${#}" -lt 4 ]]; then
        echo -e "Usage: ${0} <sftpUser> <sftpPassword> <sftpHost> <sftpPort>"
        exit 1
fi

sftpUser=${1}
sftpPassword=${2}
sftpHost=${3}
sftpPort=${4}
remote_dir="/home/vagrant"
source_dir="/home/vagrant/sftpDir"

sftpFile="/tmp/tempfile"

echo "cd ${remote_dir}" >> ${sftpFile}
echo "mget * ${source_dir}" >> ${sftpFile}
echo "quit" >> ${sftpFile}

expect -c "
spawn sftp -P ${sftpPort} -o "BatchMode=no" -b "${sftpFile}" ${sftpUser}@${sftpHost}
expect -nocase \"*Password:\" { send \"${sftpPassword}\r\"; interact }
"

rm -rf ${sftpFile}
```

`$ ./shellscript.sh user1 password@123 192.168.0.1 22`

Here, we need to provide the argument with the script itself and here we are using the plain text format for password `password@123`

- How can we use the encrypted password in the argument as this can be a risk to expose the password?
- Is there any other approach to execute this scenario?

I am not able to find any approach to pass the encrypted password with SFTP login.

Comment: I suggest to take a look at `sshpass`.

Comment: And, unless excluded explicitly, `./shellscript.sh user1 password@123 192.168.0.1 22` will go straight to your shell history file in plain text. That is generally something you want to avoid. Why can you not use `expect` or auth with public/private key exchange?

Comment: I cannot use public and private key exchange as the application is running in the container form and it can be change many times. So I cant make it passwordless authentication. Yes, you are right this approach can go straight to my shell history thats why i want to use some encrypted password in the argument and then i can decrypt the same in shell script